# How to maximize/minimize 3 variable equations?

Tags: linear-programming, computational-complexity, lagrange-multiplier

I know we can use langrangian method but i am getting confused here.
let us have equation:

$$Ax + By + Cz =D$$ (constraint) and $x,y,z$ are all non-negative.

I wanna maximize/minimze $f(x,y,z) =ax + by + cz$ ,How do I do it?
plz share an example too.
Here $A,B,C,a,b,c$ are the given constants.

Comment: To solve this type of problem you should use [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming).

Answer (score 0):

By Lagrange's theorem,

$$f(x)+\lambda g(x)=0$$

where $f$ is the fn. to be maximised and $g$ the given constraint

So,

$$Q=ax+by+cz+\lambda(Ax+By+Cz-D)=0$$

Now just compute $$ \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=0$$

$$ \frac{\partial Q}{\partial y}=0$$

$$ \frac{\partial Q}{\partial z}=0$$

and express $x,y,z$ in terms of $\lambda$ and then substitute in $g(x)$ to find $\lambda$ and eventually $x,y,z$.

Comment: \lambda\ can't be expressed in terms of x,y,z as ∂Q/∂x=0 i--> a+\lambda\ A=0

Comment: it is a linear function REMEMBER

Comment: Then, it would mean there aren't any maxima or minima. For linear functions, there are a ton of values that satisfy your constraint equation, but for those same values of $(x,y,z)$, the equation to be maximised assumes many values between $(-\infty, \infty)$. So, there isn't any maximum or minimum for your equation

Comment: Sorry,I updated question. Now say we have equations x+2y+3z=6 ,x>=0,y>=0 and z>=0 then minimize: f(x,y,z) :10x+y+5z then lowest value will be 3